# How to Select the best scores from my classes's latest test

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting the results to show up right, I want a list of all the students, with their highest scores. My table is setup to record each attempt at taking the test, so each student has multiple scores.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT o1.student_id, o1.max_score, o2.course_id max_score
FROM (
SELECT student_id, MAX( test_result ) max_score
FROM  test_scores
WHERE test_scores.course_id = $course_id
GROUP BY score DESC
)o1
JOIN  test_scores o2 ON ( o2.score = o1.max_score AND o2.student_id = o1.student_id ) 
GROUP BY o1.max_score DESC
```

I get these results:

```
course_id   max_score   student_id_of_max_score
1   100 23
1   90  17
1   80  16
1   60  11
1   40  18
1   39  17*
1   33  1
1   0   11*
```

I should add that the problem is the rows where there are duplicate student ids - marked with an asterisk. I only want the highest score per course.

Comment: .... And what is wrong with those results?  Why doesn't the last column name in the results match the query given?

Comment: Matt: It matches the query given, but I need to modify the query so that it only takes the highest score for each student's attempt at the course

Comment: I think you're using `GROUP BY` in the wrong context. Also, this might sound dumb but what does `o1` and `o2` signify? Also, `DESC` cannot follow on your `GROUP BY`, I think it can only be used after `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason that

```
SELECT course_id, student_id, MAX(score)
FROM test_scores
GROUP BY course_id, student_id
```

wouldn't be sufficient?

Comment: `SELECT course_id, student_id, MAX(score)
FROM test_scores
WHERE course_id = 1
GROUP BY course_id, student_id
ORDER BY student_id DESC`